# NoClassDefFoundError com.google.common.collect.Lists

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey (or attempting to) in order to develop a RESTful API + some JSP pages on App Engine. The error I am getting clearly seems to indicate a problem with guava.

> [INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: Error starting handlers [INFO] GCLOUD:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists

My understanding was that for the version of Jersey I should use a specifically repackaged version of guava to match. Is this incorrect? What version of Guava do I need to add as a dependency to finally be gone with this error message?

This is my dependency tree according to maven. Guava can be found on the second line.

```
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.9.48:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.25:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.5.0-b30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.5.0-b30:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.5.0-b30:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.5.0-b30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.5.0-b30:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-mvc-jsp:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-mvc:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] \- javax.ejb:javax.ejb-api:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO]    \- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
```

This is the lib folder of my compilation target, Guava is in there and I don't see a conflict for it.

```
aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b30.jar
appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.48.jar
hk2-api-2.5.0-b30.jar
hk2-locator-2.5.0-b30.jar
hk2-utils-2.5.0-b30.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.ejb-api-3.2.jar
javax.inject-2.5.0-b30.jar
javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
jersey-client-2.25.jar
jersey-common-2.25.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar
jersey-guava-2.25.jar
jersey-media-jaxb-2.25.jar
jersey-mvc-2.4.jar
jersey-mvc-jsp-2.4.jar
jersey-server-2.25.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

Previously I had a similar error, for presumably similar reasons but that seemed to go away after changing to the current Guava version (to repackaged 2.25 from 22.0 official) and running maven clean install..

> [INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: failed
>   JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@44578632:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ModelProcessorUtil.enhanceResource(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/server/model/RuntimeResource;Lorg/glassfish/jersey/server/model/ResourceModel$Builder;Ljava/util/List;)V

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm painfully close to giving up on Jersey entirely after previous struggles.

Help me Obi Wan Kenobi. You're my only hope.

Comment: Please do not post text as images, instead copy-paste (and format) it inside your post. Thx.

Comment: Changed it to a code section.

Comment: Does this issue resolve? Are you still struggling with the error?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I resolved this issue, and some people may not consider downgrading versions a solution as it isn't always a desirable thing to do. However I cared more about getting things working than being bleeding edge.

1. Downgrade jersey, jersey-guava and all accompanying jersey- libraries to 2.22.1 from 2.25
2. Downgrade h2k-api, h2k-locator, h2k-utils to 2.4.0 from 2.5.0 to match.

This project targeted app-engine version 1.9.44